# Data View Web Part: Hide or show fields dynamically based on input

Tags: 2010, data-form-web-part

I have a list that I build and a data form web part that will allow users to add to the list. How can I make various parts of the form hide or show based on the values of other fields in the form as the user fills it out?

Comment: With the Enterprise license, you can use InfoPath to customise list forms. What you describe can be done without code, with just a few clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create some javascript functions that show/hide fields or modify classes of the form fields to show/hide the input forms that are and aren't relavant.